# Multi-index - get maximum of second index for each first index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have dataframe with a multi-index which looks like the following:

```
ts                   ts2
2018-05-24 23:00:00  2018-05-24 00:00:00  5
                     2018-05-24 00:15:00  4 
                     2018-05-24 00:30:00  6 
                     2018-05-24 00:45:00  7
```

I would like to get for each datetime in index 1 the maximum value of index 2:

```
2018-05-24 23:00:00  2018-05-24 00:45:00  7
```

This cant be so difficult but somehow I cant manage it.

I tried a for loop slicing

```
for ts, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
   print(new_df)
```

which leads to a new dataframe per ts .... 
Furthermore, I am able to obtain the maximum index of the new_df

```
new_df.index.max()
```

With these info, I should be able to select the correct value (index pair) and build the desired dataframe. However, I cant manage it.....

any help appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and select by positions with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[df.reset_index().groupby('ts')['ts2'].idxmax()]
print (df)
                                         val
ts                  ts2                     
2018-05-24 23:00:00 2018-05-24 00:45:00    7
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html), but first [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_index()
df = df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df)
                                         val
ts                  ts2                     
2018-05-24 23:00:00 2018-05-24 00:45:00    7
```